# Qooxdoo - VirtualTree and Icon reloading

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm using a VirtualTree with an icon property in the node model.

I also added an "iconOptions" property like this :

```
  tree.setIconOptions({ 
    converter : function(value, model) { 
      if (model.isLoading()) return "resource/labomep/loading22.gif"; 
      return value; 
    } 
  });
```

Everything work fine except the fact that Qooxdoo is checking icon files each time a node appears, even if its icon has already been loaded (and displayed).

The server is responding 304 each time but this is making a lot of unnessary requests.

What did I do wrong ?